# Build Javascript from ts_lib Bazel with dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, bazel

How do you build a javascript binary from `ts_libs`? The output of `ts_lib` is declaration files e.g. `*.d.ts` as explained on the readme. It also explains how to get javascript out as doing this.

```
ts_library(
    name = "compile",
    srcs = ["thing.ts"],
    deps = [":someother_ts_lib"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "thing.js",
    srcs = ["compile"],
    # Change to es6_sources to get the 'prodmode' JS
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

my_rule(
    name = "uses_js",
    deps = ["thing.js"],
)
```

My question is how do I access the javascript of a `ts_lib` plus all its dependencies as a dependency of a target? When I add `:thing.js` as a dep it only pulls in the one js file, not the whole graph.

Comment: youll want to use the providers not a filegorup if you're doing a custom rule, look at how nodejs_binary does it https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/internal/node/node.bzl#L140

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was worried I would have to wrap up all the typescript code into filegroups to create a binary but this looks a lot better.